# Network goerli doesn’t exist

Tags: integration-testing

```
Hye
```

everyone, I am facing issue with deployment  related on goerli Testnetwork, I tried on many youtube videos follow along their procedure but it still shows ( Network Goerli doesn’t exist).    Actually rinkeby testnework does not working , if any would have any info about rinkeby then It would be very for me , otherwise please help in goerli network issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qesyv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No support for goearli

please user polygon : mumbai testnet